# Binding two Strings (Concatenation) in an image Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Am having a scenario , where i have a   `BaseImageUrl` **String**
 `private const string BaseImageUrl = "http://eamobiledirectory.com/cooperp/Images/app_images/";`

for the images i want to retrieve into the `Image` view in `Xaml` plus concatenating it with a string value  `office_photo` which has the exact image name ***forexample*** `flower.jpg` and   is got after deserializing JSON and it comes as a List  , below is my Model class :

```
public class Adverts
    {
            public string office_photo { get; set; }
            public DateTime entryDate { get; set; }
    }
```

so what i want is how to concatenate the `BaseUrl` and `office_photo` in `XAML` so that i get the complete link to images .

below is my Image in the ListView :

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewTest" HasUnevenRows="true">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Image  Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding office_photo}" x:Name="advertImage"
                                WidthRequest="200"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the two strings in a new property in your view modem and bind to that property. It's really simple and one line of code :-)

Something like this:

```
public string PhotoUrl { get { return BaseImageUrl + office_photo; }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a IValueConverter

Something like

```
public class AddBaseUrlConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        #region IValueConverter implementation

        private const string BaseImageUrl = "http://eamobiledirectory.com/cooperp/Images/app_images/";

        public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is string && ! string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)value))  {

                return string.Format("{0}{1}", BaseImageUrl, (string)value);
            }
            return ""; // 
        }

        public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Then in your XAML something like

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            < AddBaseUrlConverter x:Key="cnvInvert"></AddBaseUrlConverter >
        </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContentPage.Resources>

        <Image  Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding office_photo, Converter={StaticResource cnvInvert}}" x:Name="advertImage" WidthRequest="200"/>
```

(not tested, but it could work)

Comment: will it make it like this `http://eamobiledirectory.com/cooperp/Images/app_images/flower.jpg`

Comment: It's a question? it should. Try

Comment: am getting  `Type AddBaseUrlConverter not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms`

Comment: I think you should add the namenspace. Something like xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Meditation;assembly=Meditation" https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/